# Dependency injection with a dependency chain of classes

Tags: java, dependency-injection, annotations, guice

Here is an artificial example to best illustrate what I need to do:

```java
interface A {}
interface B {}
interface C {}

class A_subclass1 implements A {
    B b;
}

class A_subclass2 implements A {
    B b;
}

class B_subclass implements B {
    C c;
}

class C_subclass1 implements C {}

class C_subclass2 implements C {}
```

For `A_subclass1` the version of `C` that should be used is `C_subclass1`
For `A_subclass2` the version of `C` that should be used is `C_subclass2`

In other words, I wish to compose the following object graphs:

```java
new A_subclass1(
    new B(
        new C_subclass1()));

new A_subclass2(
    new B(
        new C_subclass2()));
```

- What is the best way to wire such a dependency?
- Is there a good way within Guice to do this?
- Is there some other recommended approach?

Comment: https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/InjectingProviders

Comment: Thanks @m0skit0. I've been diving a lot into guice docs too. With injecting providers I'm wondering how will Provider<C> know whether it is the dependency chain of A_subclass1 or A_subclass2 to accordingly pick the correct subclass of C?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I misunderstood the problem. In your case you can just use a named parameter for `B_subclass` using `@Named`.

Comment: True, and thats the current best idea I have. Of having named parameters (or Qualifiers) at each level and then having the dependency chain use the right one.

The thing is, in reality it is a chain of depth 6 (class A has member B, B has member C, C has member D ....) and basically we select the correct subclass of the lowermost level based on the uppermost level. So I can definitely have qualifiers through the entire chain. Just wondering if there is a cleaner/different way to do it?

Comment: None that I can think of, sorry.

Comment: You could do it if you were able to inspect the dependency chain from your `Provider<C>`. You can do this using a `ProvisionListener`. I'm not necessarily recommending this, but it would definitely work. The code here should give you a start: https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/4.2/javadoc/com/google/inject/spi/ProvisionListener.ProvisionInvocation.html.